# Is it possible to start from a petrol pump and complete a full circle?

Tags: number-theory

Here is a question that was asked to me in the interview for an analyst role. Although the answer seems intuitive, I was unable to justify it properly using mathematical argument.

It goes like this "There are N petrol pumps in a circle having different amounts of petrol in the stock. Assume that we can travel 1 unit distance with 1 liter of petrol and the circumference of the circle is equal to the sum of petrol present in all the petrol pumps. All petrol pumps may not have the same amount of petrol. Is it possible to pick a petrol pump such that if we start from that petrol pump then we may go along a full circle?"

Can anyone help me with the answer and logical justification for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Say, we are always driving in clockwise direction.

Lemma: there is always a pump, starting from which we can reach another pump. Indeed if we draw an arc  from each pump corresponding to the amount of fuel in it in clockwise direction, then some of this arcs need to overlap (otherwise the sum of the lengths is smaller than the circumference).

If there is a pump $i$ from which we can reach the pump $j$, than it's basically the same as we remove pump $j$ and add all its fuel to pump $i$.

Then using this argument, we can remove all pumps one by one except for the last one, which now has all the fuel and it's enough to make a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Fix a direction, say clockwise. For $k \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$, call $a_k$ the amount of fuel at station $k$ and $b_k$ the amount it takes to get to the next station (clockwise). Call $c_k = a_k - b_k$. We have $\sum_{k=1}^N c_k = 0$, and we want to find $i$ such that for all integers $j \geq 0$,
$$\sum_{k=i}^{i+j} c_k \geq 0$$
where the indices are mod $N$. Take $i_1 \geq 0$ for which the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{i_1} c_k$$
is minimal, and set $i = i_1 + 1$. By minimality of this sum, it must be that
$$\sum_{k=i}^{i+j} c_k \geq 0$$
for all $j \geq 0$, because otherwise taking $i_1 = i + j$ gives a strictly smaller sum.